# How to deploy source code from multiple Eclipse projects to Google App Engine? (aka, linking two projects)

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment, projects

I am thinking of extracting some core functionality into a new Eclipse GAE project, so I don't have duplicated code. Meaning I now have two Eclipse projects; one "main" and one "util".

I have linked them together locally in Eclipse, but when I deploy the main project, the source code from the second project is not deployed.

Is it possible to specify it should also grab the source code from the secondary project when deploying?

Updates:

Using Windows 7 and its Java.

Comment: Sounds like you're on OSX? In linux you could just softlink.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Windows 7. I am hoping for a solution, by editing some xml or conf somewhere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easier than I thought.

You just have to right-click on the project then take "Properties", "Java Build Path" and then link a new "Source" folder.